# what programming languages do i need to learn to build a website where users can

Tags: build

1)make a account (register, login, recover password etc) 2)have a profile (upload profile pic) and can pay for stuff on the site. I know html and css and a little javascript already.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple programming languages that can be used to build such a site.  Most languages have web frameworks and a way to connect to a database.  A web framework will assist you in creating a HTTP server (although some languages do not require web frameworks).  You will probably need to utilize a database to store profile information.

Here are some popular languages and frameworks:

Python (A general scripting language)

- Flask (a microframework)
- Django (a high-level Python framework)

Ruby (A general scripting language)

- Rails (an open-source framework for Ruby)

PHP (Scripting language for web development)

JavaScript (A dynamic programming language)

- Node.JS  (A framework for building quick and scalable web applications)

Hopefully this will be helpful